# How to get array of values from NSDictionary array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

When I try to print array of json values in log, I get addresses instead of values. Here's how I coded.

```
NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:jsonArray.count];
            NSMutableArray *anotherTempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:jsonArray.count];
            NSDictionary *dict;
            for(dict in jsonArray)
            {
                NSString *projectName = dict[@"Name"];

                NSString *urlText = dict[@"Url"];
                NSLog(@"Url text in array = %@", urlText);

                NSString *attch = dict[@"attachmentes"];
                NSLog(@"Attached url in array = %@", attch);

                NSString *projID = dict[@"ProjectID"];
                NSLog(@"Project ID in array = %@", projID);

                SaveAttachment *saveAt = [[SaveAttachment alloc] initWithName:projectName withList:@"View"     withAttachment:@"View"];
                [tempArray addObject:saveAt];

                SaveProjectId *saveProj = [[SaveProjectId alloc] initWithProjectId:projID];
                saveProj.projectId = projID;
                [anotherTempArray addObject:saveProj];
             }
            array = tempArray;
            [self.tableViewProject reloadData];
            NSLog(@"Array of project IDs === %@", anotherTempArray); //Get values (array of project ids here.

        }
```

[image]

Comment: Share your JSON fromat...

Comment: Why you are saving saveProj ?? Save directly projID in array..

Comment: SaveProjectId is not a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
SaveProjectId *saveProj = [[SaveProjectId alloc] initWithProjectId:projID];
saveProj.projectId = projID;
[anotherTempArray addObject:saveProj];
```

with

```
[anotherTempArray addObject:projID];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your **anotherTempArray** contains objects of SaveProjectId ie, everytime in for loop you are adding **saveProj** object not **projID**. Thats why your array showing **SaveProjectId** objects.

If you want to directly save them, then use the below modification

```
[anotherTempArray addObject:projID];
```

or you can use like(this is i would prefer)

```
NSLog(@"First project ID === %@", [anotherTempArray objectAtindex:0] projectId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing SaveProjectId objects in the array, therefore when you print the content you see the address of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

your "anotherTemoArray" is having objects of SaveProbectId so you have to pass object at index to SaveProjectId and then you can see the array information

Answer (score 0):

When calling `NSLog(@"Array of project IDs === %@", anotherTempArray);` the `-(NSString*)description` method on each of the objects inside 'anotherTempArray' is being called.

In your case that means `-(NSString*)description` is being called on `SaveProjectId` objects. Override it to print out what you want... e.g.

```
-(NSString*)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SaveProjectId: %@",self.projectId];
}
```